# Set date and time in Hikvision camera from bash or REST?

Tags: onvif, python-onvif

How can I set date and time in a hikvision camera from linux command line? Or from some language, like Python, PHP, etc...
I have a computer connected to cameras, and I want to change date and time in cameras without access to browser, only from terminal.
Thanks

Comment: Could you use curl?

Comment: Yes, I can use curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the document [HIKVISION ISAPI](https://www.docdroid.net/wlD2i8v/hikvision-isapi-26-ipmd-service.pdf) . as you know, interface depends on camera firmware version.
For setting date and time for camera. you needs HTTP PUT method with URL

http://*hikvision_camera_ipaddress*[:*http_port*]**/ISAPI/System/time**.

On general, An IP camera has 3 types of time mode; NTP, manual, sync(timecorrect for HIKVISION).

It would be better for getting date and time of the camera through GET method first with the same above url.
After that you will get a hint for HTTP body for setting date and time via PUT method.

For more detail you could refer the document 8.1.9

Answer (score 1):

If your camera supports onvif you can use python library called python-onvif (for 2.x):

```
pip install onvif
```

or python-zeep-onvif(for 3+):

```
pip3 install --upgrade onvif_zeep
```

Python code:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera
camera_ip = "your camera ip"
camera_port = "your camera port, default is 80"
wsdl_path = "path to wsdl folder"
cam = ONVIFCamera(args.ip, 80, login, password, wsdl_path)
time_request = cam.devicemgmt.create_type('SetSystemDateAndTime')
time_request.DateTimeType = "Manual"
time_request.DaylightSavings = True
time_request.UTCDateTime.Time.Hour = 4 
time_request.UTCDateTime.Time.Minutes = 20
time_request.UTCDateTime.Time.Seconds = 0
cam.devicemgmt.SetSystemDateAndTime(time_request)
```

Please, check python-onvif package [page](https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif) and onvif operation [page](https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl#op.SetSystemDateAndTime) for more detailed info